# Memory usage (RAM) of Excel stays very high after a macro is executed

Tags: excel, vba, ram

This subject is not new on the web, yet not really documented.

I have an Excel document with two events (macros) that, after being executed, keep slowing down my Excel, eating up to 7 GB or RAM (out of 16). This is insane. So far, the only solution I found to reset the memory is to re-open the document (~150 MB memory usage on start).

Here is a [one-minute video](https://vimeo.com/326207798) showing strange behaviour of memory usage in my task manager after first event (see details below). When I run the second macro (around 30s in the video), the memory almost resets, but right after the macro is finished, the memory keeps getting higher and higher even though nothing is executed on the workbook.

• The first event is a manual Refresh All. My document has 36 *connection only* queries with seven transformative steps (each query is linked to a table) and the last query combine them all in a source table which is linked to a pivot table and charts. It runs smoothly but sticks the RAM from 150 MB to 4 GB, even though the refresh takes only two seconds.

• The second query is a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) import and copy/paste some data into one table. This gets the ram even higher (6/7 GB) even though the macro runs in two seconds. Every time I rerun this macro, the RAM resets to say 600 MB, then climbs back to 7 GB even though nothing is occurring anymore.

The code of this macro deletes the query and the sheet on which the csv is imported at the end of the process, plus I also tried "Application.CutCopyMode = False" in case my clipboard was responsible. But no, it's way bigger than that.

Here is the code of the second macro (bear in mind I'm new to VBA):

```
Sub importcsvdata()
Dim ActWks As Worksheet
Set ActWks = ActiveSheet
sPath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "tempo-csv"
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="tempo-csv", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & sPath & """),[Delimiter="","", Columns=68, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Name"", type text}, {""Email""" & _
        ", type text}, {""Financial Status"", type text}, {""Paid at"", type datetimezone}, {""Fulfillment Status"", type text}, {""Fulfilled at"", type datetimezone}, {""Accepts Marketing"", type text}, {""Currency"", type text}, {""Subtotal"", type text}, {""Shipping"", type text}, {""Taxes"", type text}, {""Total"", type text}, {""Discount Code"", type text}, {""Discount " & _
        "Amount"", type text}, {""Shipping Method"", type text}, {""Created at"", type datetimezone}, {""Lineitem quantity"", Int64.Type}, {""Lineitem name"", type text}, {""Lineitem price"", type text}, {""Lineitem compare at price"", type text}, {""Lineitem sku"", type text}, {""Lineitem requires shipping"", type logical}, {""Lineitem taxable"", type logical}, {""Lineitem " & _
        "fulfillment status"", type text}, {""Billing Name"", type text}, {""Billing Street"", type text}, {""Billing Address1"", type text}, {""Billing Address2"", type text}, {""Billing Company"", type text}, {""Billing City"", type text}, {""Billing Zip"", type text}, {""Billing Province"", type text}, {""Billing Country"", type text}, {""Billing Phone"", Int64.Type}, {""" & _
        "Shipping Name"", type text}, {""Shipping Street"", type text}, {""Shipping Address1"", type text}, {""Shipping Address2"", type text}, {""Shipping Company"", type text}, {""Shipping City"", type text}, {""Shipping Zip"", type text}, {""Shipping Province"", type text}, {""Shipping Country"", type text}, {""Shipping Phone"", Int64.Type}, {""Notes"", type text}, {""Not" & _
        "e Attributes"", type text}, {""Cancelled at"", type text}, {""Payment Method"", type text}, {""Payment Reference"", type text}, {""Refunded Amount"", type text}, {""Vendor"", type text}, {""Id"", Int64.Type}, {""Tags"", type text}, {""Risk Level"", type text}, {""Source"", type text}, {""Lineitem discount"", type text}, {""Tax 1 Name"", type text}, {""Tax 1 Value""," & _
        " type text}, {""Tax 2 Name"", type text}, {""Tax 2 Value"", type text}, {""Tax 3 Name"", type text}, {""Tax 3 Value"", type text}, {""Tax 4 Name"", type text}, {""Tax 4 Value"", type text}, {""Tax 5 Name"", type text}, {""Tax 5 Value"", type text}, {""Phone"", Int64.Type}, {""Receipt Number"", type text}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Extracted Date"" = Table.TransformColumns(#""Change" & _
        "d Type"",{{""Paid at"", DateTime.Date}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Sorted Rows"" = Table.Sort(#""Extracted Date"",{{""Paid at"", Order.Ascending}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Replaced Value"" = Table.ReplaceValue(#""Sorted Rows"",""."","","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{""Total""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type1"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Replaced Value"",{{""Total"", Currency.Type}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Added Conditio" & _
        "nal Column"" = Table.AddColumn(#""Changed Type1"", ""Custom"", each if Text.Contains([Payment Method], ""PayPal"") then ""PayPal"" else if Text.Contains([Payment Method], ""Stripe"") then ""Stripe"" else null )" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Added Conditional Column"""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""tempo-csv""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [tempo-csv]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "tempo_table"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActWks.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Janvier" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_janvier").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("janvier").Range("Recettes_janvier[Date de commande]").End(Excel.xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("janvier").Range("Recettes_janvier[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("janvier").Range("Recettes_janvier[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("janvier").Range("Recettes_janvier[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("janvier").Range("Recettes_janvier[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("janvier").Range("Recettes_janvier[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Février" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_février").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("février").Range("Recettes_février[Date de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("février").Range("Recettes_février[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("février").Range("Recettes_février[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("février").Range("Recettes_février[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("février").Range("Recettes_février[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("février").Range("Recettes_février[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Mars" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_mars").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("mars").Range("B14:B1500").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("mars").Range("C14:C1500").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("mars").Range("D14:D1500").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("mars").Range("E14:E1500").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("mars").Range("F14:F1500").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("mars").Range("G14:G1500").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Avril" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_avril").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("avril").Range("Recettes_avril[Date de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("avril").Range("Recettes_avril[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("avril").Range("Recettes_avril[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("avril").Range("Recettes_avril[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("avril").Range("Recettes_avril[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("avril").Range("Recettes_avril[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Mai" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_mai").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("mai").Range("Recettes_mai[Date de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("mai").Range("Recettes_mai[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("mai").Range("Recettes_mai[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("mai").Range("Recettes_mai[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("mai").Range("Recettes_mai[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("mai").Range("Recettes_mai[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Juin" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_juin").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("juin").Range("Recettes_juin[Date de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("juin").Range("Recettes_juin[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("juin").Range("Recettes_juin[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("juin").Range("Recettes_juin[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("juin").Range("Recettes_juin[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("juin").Range("Recettes_juin[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Juillet" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_juillet").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("juillet").Range("Recettes_juillet[Date de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("juillet").Range("Recettes_juillet[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("juillet").Range("Recettes_juillet[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("juillet").Range("Recettes_juillet[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("juillet").Range("Recettes_juillet[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("juillet").Range("Recettes_juillet[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Août" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_août").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("août").Range("Recettes_août[Date de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("août").Range("Recettes_août[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("août").Range("Recettes_août[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("août").Range("Recettes_août[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("août").Range("Recettes_août[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("août").Range("Recettes_août[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Septembre" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_septembre").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("septembre").Range("Recettes_septembre[Date de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("septembre").Range("Recettes_septembre[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("septembre").Range("Recettes_septembre[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("septembre").Range("Recettes_septembre[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("septembre").Range("Recettes_septembre[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("septembre").Range("Recettes_septembre[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Octobre" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_octobre").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("octobre").Range("Recettes_octobre[Date de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("octobre").Range("Recettes_octobre[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("octobre").Range("Recettes_octobre[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("octobre").Range("Recettes_octobre[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("octobre").Range("Recettes_octobre[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("octobre").Range("Recettes_octobre[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Novembre" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_novembre").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("novembre").Range("Recettes_novembre[Date de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("novembre").Range("Recettes_novembre[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("novembre").Range("Recettes_novembre[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("novembre").Range("Recettes_novembre[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("novembre").Range("Recettes_novembre[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("novembre").Range("Recettes_novembre[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Décembre" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Recettes_décembre").ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=True
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Paid at]").Copy
        Worksheets("décembre").Range("Recettes_décembre[Date de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("décembre").Range("Recettes_décembre[N° de commande]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Billing Name]").Copy
        Worksheets("décembre").Range("Recettes_décembre[Client]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Vendor]").Copy
        Worksheets("décembre").Range("Recettes_décembre[Type]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Total]").Copy
        Worksheets("décembre").Range("Recettes_décembre[Montant]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Worksheets("tempo-csv").Range("tempo_table[Custom]").Copy
        Worksheets("décembre").Range("Recettes_décembre[Paiement]").Find("").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Else:
    End If
    Sheets("tempo-csv").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries("tempo-csv").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

What could help resolve this memory issue? I found no way to reset the memory usage. Besides, I'm not even sure where the problem lies.

Memory usage (RAM) of Excel stays very high after a macro is executed.

Comment: Tip #1: Take a look at your code. There's a lot of duplicated lines. They are reused depending on name of active sheet. You have to push it into subroutine. Tip#2: Do not use Copy-PasteSpecial. This method is very high memory consuming. Replace it with `DestinationSheet.Range("Something") = SourceSheet.Range("Whatever")`

Comment: Since you only want Value from the ranges, you could have a Variant variable to store the columns Value, then assign the destination's value from the Variant.